# How to create list of base classes using list of nested classes via generic without casting

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I would like to have an extension method for `ICollection<T2>` witch returns to me `IReadOnlyCollection<T1>`. All this I need in order not repeat myself in code. I have the following code:

```
public static IReadOnlyCollection<T1> All<T1, T2>(this ICollection<T2> storage) where T1 : T2
{
    if (storage.Count > 0)
    {
        return new List<T1>(storage);
    }
    else
    {
        return new List<T1>();
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't compile.
So lets look at a bit simpler example of above:

```
public interface IDatabase {}
public class Database : IDatabase, IDisposable {}

public static IReadOnlyCollection<T1> All<T1, T2>(this ICollection<T2> storage) where T2 : T1 where T1 : new()
{
    // compiles
    List<Database> derivedList = new List<PublishedDatabase>();
    List<IDatabase> baseList = new List<IPublishedDatabase>(derivedList);

    // doesn't compile
    // with casting it works
    List<T2> derivedListT = new List<T2>();
    List<T1> baseList1T = new List<T1>(derivedListT/* as IEnumerable<T1>*/);

    //...
}
```

Can I create a list of base classes using list of nested classes via generic without casting ?

Comment: Why dont you want to cast?

Comment: cause it's prohibited by our own code analyzers

Answer (score 1):

I maybe misunderstanding the constraints here, but you could tentatively use `dynamic` to *hoodwink* the analyzers

```
public static IReadOnlyCollection<T1> All<T1, T2>(this ICollection<T2> storage) where T2: T1
{
    dynamic temp = storage;
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<T1>(new List<T1>(temp));
}

...

var list = new List<SomeChild>()
               {
                  new SomeChild()
               };

var interfaces = list.All<ISomeBase, SomeChild>();
```

<sub>***Note*** : If your code analyzers are complaining about casts, you'd think they would complain even harder about `dynamic`... Also completely untested, and there is probably a better way to do this</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code for the extension method like this

```
public static IReadOnlyCollection<T1> All<T1>(this ICollection<T1> storage)
        {
            if(storage.Count > 0)
            {
                return new List<T1>(storage);
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<T1>();
            }
        }
```

and then you can call it like this:

```
public static void Run()
        {
           ICollection<IDatabase> databases= new List<IDatabase>(){ new Database()};
           databases.All();
        }
```

Comment: I need `T2`, `T1` cause `T2` is `IDisposable` and `T1` is not. So `T2 : T1, IDisposable`. I would like to return smth that is not disposable.